# WordPress: redirect to a custom page by getting the link from input field

Tags: php, wordpress, function, redirect, authentication

I have the following input field:

```
<input class="" type="text" name="wp_redirect_to_custom_page" id="wp_redirect_to_custom_page" value="">
```

And i'm using the following function for redirecting after login:

```
/**
 * Redirect after Login
 */
    public function redirect_after_login ( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
        if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
            return var_dump($redirect_to);
        }
        return home_url();
    }
```

I want to get the input field name attribute, which will be the url to the page, and paste it into the funciton. How it can be done ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to check this function given here.
  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the value of a input field then you should check out `get_option()`.

```
get_option( string $option, mixed $default = false )
```

*Retrieves an option value based on an option name.*

Check out the [docs for more info](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/).

Comment: Please provide a working example with my function above

Comment: I've given you all the information you need to write the code for yourself. There's no reason for us to write the code for you.